# PHP error while update mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have an update function in my website, when I run my update.php the error comes up.

(This is the error)

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\Xampp\htdocs\DBLogistic\update.php on line 9
```

(Here is my update.php)

```
<?php
include('connectdb.php');

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

$sql ="UPDATE tbluser SET userNm='$_POST['newname']', userFullNm='$_POST['newfullname']', userEmail='$_POST['newemail']', userPhone='$_POST['newcontact']', userLvlId='$_POST['newlevel']', userStatus='$_POST['newstatus']' WHERE userId='$_POST['id']'"; //this is line 9

mysql_query($sql, $con);

}

?>
```

Thank you for help, do ask me for more information if needed.

Comment: You have a problem with escaping your quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
include('connectdb.php');

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

$sql ="UPDATE tbluser SETuserNm='".$_POST['newname']."',      userFullNm='".$_POST['newfullname']."', userEmai l='".$_POST['newemail']."'...";
 //... Represents the rest of the query
mysql_query($sql, $con); }

?>
```

Use the quotes in the similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Change all `'$_POST['value']'` to `"$_POST['value']"` because it does not understand the value in `''`.